# WebDeploy Jenkins gets Error: Cannot write configuration file

Tags: iis, jenkins, deployment, msbuild, msdeploy

We have configured a job where to build and deploy automatically on each commit on bitbucket. We are successfully builds and package the solution by using msbuild but the following error occurs when we try to deploy it using msdeploy.

```
Error Code: ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_APPHOSTCONFIG
More Information: An error occurred when committing changes to the IIS Configuration System. The identity performing the operation was 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_APPHOSTCONFIG.
Error: Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config
Error: Cannot write configuration file
```

I looked into the file and gave permission for the SYSTEM user but that did not fix the problem. Following is the command we are using for msdeploy.

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package="D:\Deploy\*****.zip" -dest:auto,computerName=localhost
```

This build is done in a load balanced enviornment where we use two servers. So application provisioning is enabled. How to fix this issue?

iis version - 8.5
OS - Windows 2012 R2

Comment: You have given access to the inetsrv folder or just only to the applicationHost.config file.

Comment: Yes, tried it but didn't work

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2023852/you-receive-an-error-when-you-use-the-web-deployment-tool-web-deploy-as-a-non-administrative-user

Comment: If SYSTEM user didn't work, you can change the logon user of Jenkins windows service and  provide respective permissions as [Microsoft Resolution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2023852/you-receive-an-error-when-you-use-the-web-deployment-tool-web-deploy-as-a-non-administrative-user)

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: Is that User in local admins group?

Comment: This is user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, wouldn't it be by default in local admins group?

Comment: Try to create with a new user and add that user to the local admin group, local admin people can deploy the application using msdeploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving permission for shared applicationhost.config file the problem was fixed. Here is a guide to how to give permission for shared applicationhost.config file.

https://forums.iis.net/t/1175866.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and for me it turned out, that the site was only registered as a folder in IIS-Manager.

Right click on the site int IIS-Manager and then:
"Deploy | Convert to Application"
solved it for me